# Jetty: java.lang.VerifyError: org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/ServletHandler

Tags: java, android, cling

I try to build Android project using Android Studio 1.0.2. 
This project uses following libraries: Cling UPNP/DLNA and Jetty.
When I run APK on device i get this error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/ServletHandler
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.newServletHandler(ServletContextHandler.java:207)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.getServletHandler(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.addServlet(ServletContextHandler.java:324)
            at org.fourthline.cling.transport.impl.jetty.JettyServletContainer.registerServlet(JettyServletContainer.java:132)
            at org.fourthline.cling.transport.impl.AsyncServletStreamServerImpl.init(AsyncServletStreamServerImpl.java:74)
            at org.fourthline.cling.transport.RouterImpl.startAddressBasedTransports(RouterImpl.java:434)
            at org.fourthline.cling.transport.RouterImpl.enable(RouterImpl.java:132)
            at org.fourthline.cling.android.AndroidRouter.enable(AndroidRouter.java:92)
            at org.fourthline.cling.UpnpServiceImpl.<init>(UpnpServiceImpl.java:87)
            at org.fourthline.cling.android.AndroidUpnpServiceImpl$1.<init>(AndroidUpnpServiceImpl.java:54)
            at org.fourthline.cling.android.AndroidUpnpServiceImpl.onCreate(AndroidUpnpServiceImpl.java:54)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2656)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5226)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm using this dependencies (.JARs in libs folder):

```
jetty-security-8.1.8.v20121106.jar
jetty-http-8.1.8.v20121106.jar
jetty-continuation-8.1.8.v20121106.jar
jetty-io-8.1.8.v20121106.jar
jetty-util-8.1.8.v20121106.jar
jetty-server-8.1.8.v20121106.jar
jetty-servlet-8.1.8.v20121106.jar
jetty-client-8.1.8.v20121106.jar
servlet-api-3.0.1.jar
```

I try to add this

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
```

to "android" section of build.gradle, but it did not help.
Has anyone encountered similar?

Comment: Are there error messages above the exception in logcat?  Some lines with "VFY" in the text?  What version of Android is the device using?

Comment: Yes. Android 4.2.2 Cyanogen Mode 10.1. Full log: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/715bd4394514d4668f0b

Comment: Looks like you're missing a bunch of stuff from org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.  Is that not being linked in?